# RxJava 1 and 2 with different results for Completable.andThen()

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I created the following class to demonstrate de problem:

```java
public class TestRx {

    public void run() {
        // RxJava2
        new CompositeDisposable().add(completableRxJava2()
                .subscribeOn(io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers.computation())
                .andThen(testSingleRxJava2())
                .observeOn(io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers.newThread())
                .subscribe(
                        this::success,
                        Throwable::printStackTrace));

        // RxJava1
        new CompositeSubscription().add(completableRxJava1()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .andThen(testSingleRxJava1())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .subscribe(
                        this::success,
                        Throwable::printStackTrace));
    }

    private io.reactivex.Completable completableRxJava2() {
        return io.reactivex.Completable.fromAction(() ->
                System.out.println("completableRxJava2 " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
    }

    private io.reactivex.Single<String> testSingleRxJava2() {
        return io.reactivex.Single.fromCallable(() -> {
            System.out.println("testSingleRxJava2 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return "END";
        });
    }

    private Completable completableRxJava1() {
        return Completable.fromAction(() ->
                System.out.println("completableRxJava1 " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
    }

    private Single<String> testSingleRxJava1() {
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
            System.out.println("testSingleRxJava1 " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return "END";
        });
    }

    private void success(final String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

When I executed the `run()` method this is the output:

```
completableRxJava2 RxComputationThreadPool-1
testSingleRxJava2 RxComputationThreadPool-1
END

completableRxJava1 RxIoScheduler-2
```

I don't understand some things in this result.

1. Why `testSingleRxJava2` is not executed on `RxNewThreadScheduler`?
2. Why RxJava1 does not execute the `testSingleRxJava1` method?

Sometimes the output is even more confusing and the return is only this:

```
completableRxJava2 RxComputationThreadPool-1
testSingleRxJava2 RxComputationThreadPool-1
END
```

No output of RxJava1.

Why this happens?

RxJava1 version: 1.3.8
RxJava2 version: 2.2.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why testSingleRxJava2 is executed not on RxNewThreadScheduler?

`observeOn` affects the downstream operations, so if you want testSingleRxJava2 to execute on new thread you should change your code to:

```
    .observeOn(io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers.newThread())
    .andThen(testSingleRxJava2())
```

> 2. Why RxJava1 does not execute the testSingleRxJava1 method?

it might be because when you are running that code the main thread is finishing before the io thread get a chance to print, try adding a `Thread.sleep(1000)` in the end of your run method and it should consistently print it